# How to convert an ndarray of integers to strings and add leading 0 to elements < 10

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to convert an array of seconds of day (seconds since midnight) to hh:mm:ss. It looks like datetime and pandas don't have a way to do this, so I'm writing a function to do it manually so that I can construct an ISO date/time string to pass to pandas.

```
sod = np.arange(0, 86399)
hours = sod // 3600
L = list(np.list(np.array(hours, str))
```

And this is where nothing I try works... what I want to do is something like what I would do in IDL:

```
smallHourIndices = where(L < 10)
L[smallHourIndices] = '0' + L[smallHourIndices]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.core.defchararray.zfill`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.zfill.html#numpy.core.defchararray.zfill) function in order to add a zero prefix to an array's items, but since it only accepts string type object you can first find the respective items using the intended mask then pass the string version and concatenate the result with the rest of your array.

```
In [22]: mask = hours < 10

In [23]: np.concatenate((np.core.defchararray.zfill(hours[mask].astype(str), 2), hours[~mask]))
Out[23]: 
array(['00', '00', '00', ..., '23', '23', '23'], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: This works! I wish the command didn't need to be quite so long. Also, it doesn't look like this would work if the numbers didn't happen to be sequential in the original list, would it?

Comment: @JamesPMason It's easy to write this in shorter lines but in that case it'd be more than 1 line. About working in other situations rather than sequential arrays, it definitely works because the mask has nothing to do with the order of items.

Comment: But won't the concatenate cause the final result to be in the order of elements_in_mask, elements_out_of_mask? For example, hours = [0, 12, 3], result -> ['00', '03', '12']

Comment: Obviously, In that case you can simply create a string array from the main array and replace the items that match to the mask with the result of `np.core.defchararray.zfill`.

Comment: That's similar to what I was trying earlier but I couldn't find a way to get numpy to do a replace in place. How do you do the replace?

Comment: @JamesPMason Like this `str_array[mask] = np.core.defchararray.zfill(hours[mask].astype(str), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to add trailing zeroes to L so it's a human-friendly hour. You can use `zfill`, which is a mehtod that strings have:

```
L = 3
firendly_hour = str(L).zfill(2)
print(firendly_hour)  # outputs '03'

L = 11
firendly_hour = str(L).zfill(2)
print(firendly_hour)  # outputs '11'
```

Comment: I like that this is concise, but I'm also trying to retain the array and this method results in:

    In [120]: friendly_hour = str(L).zfill(2)

    In [121]: friendly_hour[0]
    Out[121]: '['